# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: java, eclipse, stanford-nlp

I'm using Eclipse to run java program class, while I run it i got this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

then i changed the VM from the Properties > Run > VM Options, and I run the program again i got a new error,

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Incompatible initial and maximum heap sizes specified
```

I'm trying to apply stanford libraries in my program, any idea how to solve this error .

Comment: That means you allocated too much memory. Without seeing the code, I can't tell you much more than that...

Comment: What did you changed in VM options?

Comment: i change the size of the memory, at the beginning I used 50m memory, then when the first msg comes to me i change the vm to 512m i got the second msg

Comment: can you add java program class

Comment: I added, all the classes can't run when i change the VM to 512m

Comment: Can you the exact string that you have specified in VM options.

Comment: here is the string that i changed -Xms512m

Answer (score 7, accepted):

to change the VM for Eclipse you can change the amount of the MV from 
    Windows> Preferences> Java> Installed JREs 
from there select the JRE and click edit, then write in the Default VM Arguments: to -Xmx1024M or any other amount of memory ...

Comment: What is the max amount of memory I can add?

Answer (score 2):

> Error occurred during initialization of VM. Incompatible initial and maximum heap sizes specified

This probably means that you supplied both -Xms and -Xmx options, and the -Xms (initial heap size) value is larger than the -Xmx (maximum heap size) value.

---

> netbeans provide to change the -Xms only from Properties > run > VM options

I'm not a NetBeans user.  However, a brief search of the [Using NetBeans 5.0](http://netbeans.org/files/documents/40/718/UsingNetBeans5.0.pdf) manual says this is not correct:

> Setting JVM Arguments
>
> You can specify JVM arguments for the project in the Project Properties dialog
> box. Open the Project Properties dialog box and click Run in the Categories pane
> and then type a space-separated list of JVM arguments in the VM Options field.

In other words, you can set *any* JVM option that your JVM supports.

---

> here is the string that i changed -Xms512m

(Finally he tells us!!)

Add -Xmx512m as well.

For the record, the common JVM options (such as -Xmx and -Xms) are clearly documented in the manual page for the `java` command.  You should READ it CAREFULLY.

Comment: I'll guess he/she forgot an 'm' suffix in the Xmx

Comment: netbeans provide to change the -Xms only from Properties > run > VM options, how i can change the -Xms in netbeans..

Comment: I'm trying to run a program which contain ENR stanford nlp, and wheni try to run the first error msg appear, so i change the VM to 512m and the other error comes which appears in the question ..

Answer (score 0):

To enlarge the VM heap size use -Xmx option, this could solve the error. But it seems it's your coding problem. Perhaps code is in a dead loop to create new object, or a very large object is created in you code, so I suggest you to check code first.

Comment: the error comes when I try to run Entity Named Recognition "stanford NLP" for the other features, the program run smoothly