# Exception when using Java -version

Tags: java, jvm-arguments

When using the command `java -version`, I am getting...

> Error occurred during initialization of VM java.lang.OutOfMemoryError:
>   unable to create new native thread

What is the possible solution?

Comment: Re-installing your JDK/JRE. Sounds like there's something very wrong with your installation.

Comment: 64-bit/32-bit issue? :S

Comment: 64 bit. This error started after the tomcat crashed on memory issue. Before it was working fine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9460015/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-java-heap-space

Comment: You may be missing required patches to your operating system.  What is your execution environment?

Comment: When `java -version` gives `OutOfMemoryError`, it means that it can't create the VM at all, even with the default memory settings. You could try to give it `-Xmx256M -X128M` (or other suitable memory sizes) as parameters, but the installation is definitely not "right" anymore.